# Trying to access contacts within android app keep crashing

Tags: java, android, email, android-contacts

I am trying to access the contacts through my app. So I am able to share information through mail to a friend. So far the contacts are shown but when I click on a name to add to the email the application just go back to the previous screen and the email is not sent. The edit text is not set to the contact which I have chosen.

Android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"> </uses-permission>
```

EmailSend class

```
contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
        }
    });
```

....

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         System.out.println("yo");
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String email = "";
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                Uri result = data.getData();
                Log.v("DEBUG: ", "Got a contact result: "
                        + result.toString());

                // get the contact id from the Uri
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                // query for everything email
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                        null);

                int emailIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

                // let's just get the first email
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    email = cursor.getString(emailIdx);
                    Log.v("DEBUG: ", "Got email: " + email);
                } else {
                    Log.w("DEBUG: ", "No results");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("DEBUG: ", "Failed to get email data", e);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                  cursor.close();
                }
               // EditText emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email);
                personsEmail.setText(email);
                if (email.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No email found for contact.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            break;
        }

    } else {
        Log.w("DEBUG: ", "Warning: activity result not ok");
    }
}
```

What is more puzzling is that there is nothing that appears on logcat! So it surpasses all my error checks. Any idea why the screen crashes and the email address is not added to the EditText?

Comment: what is the exception you getting? please share and if you are testing in Marshmallow you need to check permission during runtime too. In Marshmallow User has the ability to disable the access after installing application.

Comment: It says Keyboard.Facilitator onFinishInput() on logcat. Using eclipse with android plug ins. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: it's not necessary that every contact has an email id .Contacts that are synced from gmail usually have email id but contacts added manually don't have it

Comment: @VivekMishra If I don't use the ID how would I do it?

Comment: @MsYvette this is what is in my manifest:   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Comment: If a contact doesn't has an email id you can't do any thing in that case. Only thing you can do is to have a null check for your email id

Answer (score 1):

In case you are testing it in the latest OS, that means Android M, they have introduced new set of permissions, known as run-time permissions.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Check this link out and let us know if this solves the issue.

Comment: this is what is in my manifest: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" /> Do I need to look into these new permissions?

Comment: As @MsYvette said, it is just for the device on which you are testing, if it is a Marshmallow device, then you have to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr) {
        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            ContactSynRequestcontacts data = new ContactSynRequestcontacts();
```

String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

Cursor emails = contResv.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId , null, null);
            while (emails.moveToNext()) 
            { 
               String email = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                break;
            }
            emails.close();

```
            data.setName(name);
            data.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            userContactList.add(data);
        }
        phones.close();// close cursor
    }

    public class ContactSynRequestcontacts  {
    private String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    private String PhoneNumber;

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return PhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String mobile) {
        this.PhoneNumber = mobile;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can directly access the contacts without intent

Comment: I only need their email address though... so is this still helpful?

Comment: So you can get the email address as well like Name and Number

Comment: But I only need the email address I don't need a name or a number for my program. I only care about the email address.

Comment: Ok i can update the code you can check it again and used according to your need

Comment: That would be great if you could @RohitHeera thanks!